# Why would you use a supertype variable to refer to a subtype object?

Tags: java, oop

What is defferent between

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

and

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

When to use the first one and when to use the second one?

Comment: why is marked as duplicate ? can you give me the link of the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, refresh your page. It will be at the top.